# Use of await in JavaScript against synchronous functions

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

In JavaScript, not only it does not throw an error when `await` is used against a synchronous function, but it won't let the function know that it is misused that way.

What is the premise for that? Any official documentation reference?

I've come across a lot of code where `await` is used in front of synchronous functions simply because the developer did not bother checking the function's declaration. This confuses developers who support such code, further multiplying such bad practice.

And let's say somebody whats to root out all such code, and is there absolutely no way to do this?

Comment: Using `await` with a function that does not return a promise is not a syntax error and runs normally. I don't think the JavaScript engine could statically analyze for that.

Comment: @Li357 I know that it runs normally, this isn't what I asked, I asked why, and gave the explanation of why I asked it.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I also said JavaScript implementations probably can't statically analyze for a promise-returning function to warn you.

Comment: Actually, I could see maybe throwing a TypeError during runtime, though I'm not exactly sure why they don't do this. You could (maybe) prevent this with TypeScript which does static type-checking

Comment: _"because the developer did not bother checking "_ that is not the only reason for using await in front of a possibly sync function. Maybe the function result is not always needing to be a promise. For example caching ajax requests, if the request was cached just return the value otherwise return the ajax promise. Of course you could always do `Promise.resolve(cachevalue)` but i personally wouldnt want to always have to do that

Comment: @PatrickEvans If the function signature and its documentation say the function is synchronous, using it as asynchronous is a terrible practice. Not only it creates a confusion, but other developers tend to create more explicit asynchronous functions just to wrap this one, because they think it is asynchronous, further complicating the code. And so on. And you end up with a lot of asynchronous-written code without reason, on the basis of a single wrong presumption underneath.

Comment: Yes in that one case it is bad, but as stated there are reasons for using await in front of what ends up being a sync call instead of async. There is no way for the js engine to know ahead of time what the return type of a function is going to be so it cant test wither or not some syntax is misused. ie: `a=()=>3` and `b=(cached)=>cached?3:fetch()` how would the engine possibly test that `await a()` is a misuse and `await b(true)` is not